# OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) too many SQL variables, while using SQL with dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe as below.

```
       activity         User_Id  \
0  VIEWED MOVIE  158d292ec18a49   
1  VIEWED MOVIE  158d292ec18a49   
2  VIEWED MOVIE  158d292ec18a49   
3  VIEWED MOVIE  158d292ec18a49   
4  VIEWED MOVIE  158e00978d7a6c   

                                         Media_Title Media_Type User_Rating  
0  20th Asian Athletics Championship-2013 Held At...                     NA  
1                                 Tu Majha Saangaati                     NA  
2                                       Home Cooking                     NA  
3                                         Mix Dil Se                     NA  
4                  Value, Virtues, Ethics & Morality                     NA
```

I am trying to write an SQL query using sqldf package of pandasql as below.

```
distinct_activity_user = pandasql.sqldf(" select User_Id from pmm_activity", locals())
```

The error i am getting is :

```
OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) too many SQL variables [SQL: 'INSERT INTO pmm_activity (activity, "User_Id", "Media_Title", "Media_Type", "User_Rating") VALUES
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be a problem related to blank spaces in you column names. I experienced that when I tried to work with the data you provided. I have an example using `sqlite3`. Here is an example that might be a solution to your problem:

```
import sqlite3 as sql
import pandas as pd

file         = "..../movie.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(file, sep=";", dtype='unicode' )
```

Here is what the datarame looks like

[image]

```
conn = sql.connect('movie2.db')
df.to_sql('movie', conn)
conn = sql.connect('movie2.db')
Movie = pd.read_sql('SELECT distinct "User_Id  "  FROM movie', conn)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A couple of potential causes:

1. This issue is registered on the git repo with a suggestion to upgrade pandas depending on your version number

https://github.com/yhat/pandasql/issues/72

2. If the dataframe in the question is the full dataframe you experience the exception on, this won’t apply…but if it’s a representative sample, this issue could be a cause. So, try the limiting/restricting initial dataframe suggestion:

https://github.com/yhat/pandasql/issues/79

Otherwise, I would try removing all columns except User_Id from your initial dataframe to test if this works. If it does I would add media_type in next to see if the blanks are the cause and so on.