# Python pandasql sqldf giving "too many SQL variables" when number of values (RxC) in dataframe is over 999

Tags: python, pandas, pandasql

Background:

I'm ultimately trying to join two tables that reside in completely different databases. I've loaded the data into dataframes with the intent of executing a SQL join through sqldf (both because the join is on an inequality and because I'm very comfortable in SQL, but less so in python).

Environment:

- Jupyter notebook on Anaconda
- PandaSQL 0.7.3
- Numpy 1.14.3
- SQLAlchemy 1.2.7
- Python 3.6.5
- Windows 10

Issue:

I can reproduce this problem using a simple built-in dataset and a very simple query. The following code:

```
from pandasql import sqldf, load_meat
meat = load_meat()
print(sqldf("SELECT * FROM meat;",locals()))
```

returns:

> OperationalError: too many SQL variables

Ultimately, this traces to sqlite3 where an "INSERT INTO" statement is using an 8-tuple set of parameters for each row and then passing values into those parameters:

```
SQL: 'INSERT INTO meat (date, beef, veal, pork, lamb_and_mutton, broilers, other_chicken, turkey) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?),

....

(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'] 
[parameters: ('1944-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 751.0, 85.0, 1280.0, 89.0, None, None, None, '1944-02-01 00:00:00.000000', 713.0, 77.0, 1169.0, 72.0, None, None, None,
....
```

I've also reproduced this error by loading a simple CSV into a dataframe (500,2). If I reduce the CSV/df from 500 rows to 499, then sqldf works fine.

In search of a solution, I've read plenty about the 999-parameter limit of SQLite. However, I've seen [plenty](https://community.alteryx.com/t5/Data-Science-Blog/pandasql-Make-python-speak-SQL/ba-p/138435) [of](http://blog.yhat.com/posts/pandasql-sql-for-pandas-dataframes.html) [examples](https://github.com/yhat/pandasql/blob/master/examples/demo.py) using the built-in datasets. The last example, in particular, is directly from the pandasql repository. Running the code in that example, the section dealing with the iris data (150x6) runs fine while the meat data (827x8) causes the parameter error described above.

I found one other reference to this problem on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50506563/operationalerror-sqlite3-operationalerror-too-many-sql-variables-while-using), but there's been no activity there.